# Append Existing Custom Node Group in Blender

Tags: python-3.x, blender, bpy

I tried to append my blend file and import the node group in my new environment. I tried different methods on how to append my own custom node group in my environment, and still not working. Here's my boilerplate.

```
class SHADER(Operator):
bl_idname = "material.append_shader_nodes"
bl_label = "Add Shader"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


def execute(self,context):
    # Importing the blend file (working)
    import_from_library('shader');
    
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
    
    # Creates new Material
    npr_material = bpy.data.materials.new(name='SHADER')
    npr_material.use_nodes = True

    # Remove the default shader
    npr_material.node_tree.nodes.remove(npr_material.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF'))
    material_output = npr_material.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')

    # Problem
    SHADER = bpy.data.node_groups['NPREEVEE'] # Import my custom node group from my different blend file

    # link shader to material
    npr_material.node_tree.links.new(material_output.inputs[0], SHADER.outputs[0])

    # set activer material to your new material
    bpy.context.object.active_material = npr_material
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

It seems like it didn't import my node group, but when I tried to manually add my custom node group, it displayed on my materials properties. I'm not totally familiar with this package. Is this is a bug or there is something that I missed while creating my node group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to import a file from another blend file. Using the `os library`, you can import your selected blend file and make parameters for it, and then you can import your custom node group by using `bpy.data.libraries.load`.

Here is my example:

```
# Importing necessary libraries
import bpy
import os

# Operator class for importing custom nodes
class AppendCustomNode(Operator):
    bl_idname = "append_cutom_nodes.op"
    bl_label = "IMPORT YOUR CUSTOM NODE"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def __init__(self):
        # Define the path to the blend file containing the custom node
        self.source_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "FOLDER_NAME", "BLENDER_FILENAME.blend")

    def import_file(self):
        # Check if the file exists
        if not os.path.isfile(self.source_file):
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "File not found: {}".format(self.source_file))
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def import_node_group(self, node_group_name):
        # Load the custom node group from the blend file
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(self.source_file, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
            if node_group_name in data_from.node_groups:
                data_to.node_groups = [node_group_name]

        # Check if the node group was successfully loaded
        if not data_to.node_groups or not data_to.node_groups[0]:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Failed to load the node group: {}".format(node_group_name))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # Report successful import
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Successfully appended node group: {}".format(node_group_name))
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def execute(self, context):
        # Import the blend file
        if self.import_file() == {'CANCELLED'}:
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # Import the custom node group
        self.import_node_group("YOUR_CUSTOM_NODE")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```